# System.Net.Http.Handlers.ProgressMessageHandler Returns 100% Immediately

Tags: c#, upload, windows-runtime, httpclient, progress

I have a WinRT application (8.0, not 8.1, so I can't use Windows.Web.HttpClient) where I am uploading large files to a site. I am using System.Net.Http.HttpClient with the System.Net.Http.Handlers.ProgressMessageHandler from the Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client nuget package for the purposes of tracking progress.

No matter how big a file I upload, I always seem to get the HttpSendProgress event called once, and only once, with 100% progress (and totalBytes == sentBytes). However the file doesn't actually complete uploading to the site until sometime after the event fired, depending on file size and whether I've limited the upload speed etc. The upload does work, but the progress reporting is useless.

I used a network monitoring tool and could see the data being transferred slowly after the progress event was called (when I let the app run after stopping on a break point) - but I only got the event raised one time and with 100% progress before the upload finished.

I presume the HttpClient is writing to some kind of buffer which is happening much more quickly than the actual upload, but I can't figure out how to change/prevent that, or what the point of the ProgressMessageHandler class is if it always works this way.

At the moment the code I'm using looks something like the following;

```
public static async Task<string> UploadDataAsync(string uploadUrl, byte[] data, string contentTypeHeader, string oauthHeader, Action<long, long?> progressCallback)
{
    var ph = new System.Net.Http.Handlers.ProgressMessageHandler();
    if (progressCallback != null)
    {
        ph.HttpSendProgress += (sender, args) =>
        {
            progressCallback(args.BytesTransferred, args.TotalBytes);
        };
    }

    var client = HttpClientFactory.Create(ph);
    client.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 20, 0);

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(oauthHeader)) 
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", oauthHeader);

    var content = new ByteArrayContent(data);
    content.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", contentTypeHeader);
    var postResponse = await client.PostAsync(new Uri(uploadUrl), content);
    var result = await postResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    if (!postResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        throw new OAuthException(result);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Just to add to my question - I've found several posts on line (some on Stack Overflow) with the same symptom, but often the suggestion is use httpclient and progressmessagehandler (which is what I'm trying to do), or use Windows.Web.HttpClient which I can't at the moment due to tooling compatibility etc. While all of these sound similar, they don't seem to be duplicates of my question.

Comment: I should also mention that code after the await client.PostAsync doesn't resume execution until much later after the progress event fires, and when it appears the data has actually been uploaded. It therefore seems the method is waiting on the data to transmit, but reporting progress based on writing to some kind of buffer ?

Comment: Try using [BackgroundUploader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br207140) instead. It will return an object called [UploadOperation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.backgroundtransfer.uploadoperation) which will allow you to access things like the `Progress`.

Comment: Thanks Nate, but there are reasons why I'm using HttpClient (reasons of varying validity admittedly), which is why I haven't used backgrounduploader or tried a solution that involves manually copying the lower level streams myself. Mostly, I want to know why this doesn't work, as I'm not sure what the point of ProgressMessageHandler is if it doesn't actually report progress usefully ?

Comment: Ok, I've managed to hack the code around to use the BackgroundUploader (had to use a custom stream rather than a raw file to send all the data I need). The upload works, and so does he progress. Unfortunately the code I'm using is in an open source library and this method is reused by a bunch of other methods and classes in the same library, so I'm going to have a lot more work to do to make this work well - handling restarts of the app etc. Still confused about how to get the progressmessagehandler doing what it's supposed to.

Comment: [The Quickstart guide to Uploading files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj152727.aspx) has some explanations on how to monitor for progress.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem, Please share your solution if you found one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26210707/windows-phone-upload-file-showing-the-speed-rate

Comment: Unfortunately no. The library I was using is opens source so I modified it to support background uploads, but I never solved the original problem.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem too..does anyone have an solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same problem, and the issue was using `ByteArrayContent` for the Post call. That type doesn't get chunked by the underlying `HttpClient` (my vague understanding of how this works).

You need to use `StreamContent` to get progress updates. I used it with a `FileStream`, which worked perfect. I've seen reports that `MemoryStream` does *not* give progress. YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend chain your both tasks with `ContinueWith` and use `TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion` to give the `ProgressMessageHandler` the chance to report the progress exactly as you want.

Hope this may help.

```
postResponse.ContinueWith(task =>
     {
         if (task.Result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
         { 
         }
     }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);
```